# Sum reduction with parallel algorithm - Bad performances compared to CPU version

Tags: c, performance, opencl

I have achieved a small code for doing sum reduction of a 1D array. I am comparing a CPU sequential version and a OpenCL version.

The code is available on [this link1](http://93.184.46.144/info/sumReductionGPU.c)

The kernel code is available on [this link2](http://93.184.46.144/info/sumReductionGPU.cl)

and if you want to compile : [link3 for Makefile](http://93.184.46.144/info/Makefile)

My issue is about the bad performances of GPU version :

for size of vector lower than 1,024 * 10^9 elements (i.e with `1024, 10240, 102400, 1024000, 10240000, 102400000 elements`) the runtime for GPU version is higher (slightly higher but higher) than CPU one.

As you can see, I have taken 2^n values in order to have a compatible number of workitems with the size of a workgroup.

Concerning the number of workgroups, I have taken :

```
// Number of work-groups
  int nWorkGroups = size/local_item_size;
```

But for a high number of workitems, I wonder if the value of nWorkGroups is suitable ( for example, `nWorkGroups = 1.024 * 10^8 / 1024 = 10^5 workgroups`, isn't this too much ?? ).

I tried to modify `loca_item_size` in the range of `[64, 128, 256, 512, 1024]` but the performances remain bad for all these values.

I have good benefits only for `size = 1.024 * 10^9` elements, here are the runtimes :

```
Size of the vector
1024000000

Problem size = 1024000000

GPU Parallel Reduction : Wall Clock = 20 second 977511 micro

Final Sum Sequential = 5.2428800006710899200e+17

Sequential Reduction : Wall Clock = 337 second 459777 micro
```

From your experiences, why do I get bad performances ? I though that advantages should be more significative compared to CPU version.

Maybe someone could see into source code a main mistake because, at the moment, I can't get to solve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I can tell you some reasons:

- You don't need to write the reduction buffer. You can directly clear it in GPU memory using `clEnqueueFillBuffer()` or a helper kernel.

  `ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, reductionBuffer, CL_TRUE, 0, 
          local_item_size * sizeof(double), sumReduction, 0, NULL, NULL);`
- Dont use blocking calls, except for the last read. Otherwise you are wasting some time there.
- You are doing the last reduction in CPU. Iterative processing trough the kernel can help.
- Because if your kernel is just reducing 128 elements per pass. Your 10^9 number just gets down to 8*10^6. And the CPU does the rest. If you add there the data copy, it makes it completely non worth.
  However, if you run 3 passes at 512 elements per pass, you read out from the GPU just 10^9/512^3 = 8 values. So, the only bottleneck would be the first GPU copy and the kernel launch.

Comment: Thanks for your remark. Indeed, I realized that all OpenCL routines before "clEnqueueNDRangeKernel" takes a long time comparing to the CPU version. I think I have to only measure the runtime of "clEnqueueNDRangeKernel" function.

Comment: ok, I would like to perform a benchmark as objective as possible between CPU and GPU version : What do you think if, for OpenCL version, I put the chrono instructions between the "clEnqueueNDRangeKernel" and finalSum = 0.0; for (i=0; i<nWorkGroups; i++) finalSum += sumReduction[i];
For CPU version, I would like to put chrono between " finalSum = 0.0; for (i=0; i<nWorkItems; i++) finalSum += xInput[i];"

Comment: I think timing only the functional part of the code won't produce a very useful comparison. the GPU kernel requires the set up and transfer time before it, as well as the copying of the result back to the host.

Comment: I said this because I want to include the parallel sum reduction into a main loop to compute next values of an array with iterative process and this main loop is stopped until the total sum of error is higher than a fixed tolerance. So I am going to call NDRangeKernel a lot of times in this main loop, that's why I would like to get the performances gain for only one iteration, I mean for only one NDRangeKernel call